# Alguém explica essa mensagem do git, depois de um pull para o develop?

Tags: git

Tenho o braço develop na minha maquina local. No develop remote existem uns 10 programadores fazendo push todos os dias.

Por isso faço sempre um pull antes de fazer o merge do meu develop com o a feature123 que estou trabalhando e prestes a enviar para o braço feature123 remoto.

Fazendo o pull do develop remoto tive a seguinte mensagem:

```
$ git pull origin develop
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/.../.ssh/id_rsa':
remote: Counting objects: 193, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (193/193), done.
remote: Total 193 (delta 149), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (193/193), 30.63 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (149/149), completed with 48 local objects.
From bitbucket.org:.../....-source
 * branch                develop    -> FETCH_HEAD
   21......64........c8  develop    -> origin/develop
Auto-merging postback.php
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in postback.php
Auto-merging includes/db_manager.php
Auto-merging checkout-site.php
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Que diz que houve alguns merges automaticos e um que não foi possivel fazer automaticamente no caso no arquivo postback.php.

Em seguida pedi um status:

```
$ git status
On branch develop
Your branch and 'origin/develop' have diverged,
and have 131 and 74 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")
  (use "git merge --abort" to abort the merge)

Changes to be committed:
...
modified:   admin/details.php
...
both modified:   postback.php
```

O fato é que o que eu tenho no meu develop é exatament o que eu tinha desde o último pull ( que foi ontem a noite ). Não trabalhei no develop.

A primeira coisa que não entenedo é pq não foi possivel fazer um merge automático, já que foi feito nos outros arquivos e em nenhum deles houve mudança no branch em questão - no caso develop.

A segunda coisa que não entendo é pq foi considerado **both modified:   postback.php** modificado nos dois lados se eu não trabalhei com ele no develop local.
Eu tenho outro braço que se chama feature123 e nesse braço eu modifiquei o arquivo postback.php. Mas não foi em develop.

Alguem pode explicar pq o git mostrou essa mensagem?

Comment: Você não está na branch `feature123` e tentando fazer `pull` da `develop`?

Comment: nao, estou na branch develop

Comment: E o arquivo `postback.php` que **você modificou** foi commitado? Perceba que eu não disse enviado para o servidor, quero saber se ele foi commitado localmente.

Comment: Isso aconteceu algumas vezes, não consegui descobrir o motivo pra resolver de um forma 'correta', mas como sempre deixo sincronizado, resolvi apagando o (os) arquivo(s) local que aparecia(m) como modificado(s) (mesmo sem modificar), fazia um pull, depois commit, e depois push funcionava de novo, mas vira e mexe isso acontece, e as vezes não funciona, nesses casos preciso clonar de novo, vai ser muito útil uma resposta, pois isso deve ser problema por mau uso.

Comment: LINQ, o postback.php foi modificado e comitado no meu branch feature123.  Agora estou no branch develop. Nao tem motivo para ter modificação ou commit aqui.

Comment: @AnthraxisBR  pois é.. eu tenho que entender de onde está vindo esse mau uso.. Se de minha parte, ou do software que estou utilizando ou algum outro bug em algum outro lugar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe algumas provabilidades vou citar em ordem de relevância:

1. Alguém comitou o merge errado entre as branchs
2. Sua branch local se chama feature123 mas está apontando na develop
3. O arquivo checkout-site.php foi alterado comitado e o git não consegui entender sozinho as alterações(simples assim, isso pode acontecer);

Soluções:

1. Quero q minha develop fique igual como está no repositório:

> git fetch all
>
> git reset --hard origin/develop
>
> git pull

2. Não alterei o arquivo checkout-site.php quero que somente ele fique igual ao repositório:

> git fetch all
>
> git checkout-site.php
>
> git pull

3 Quero resolver o conflito afinal de contas quero entender o que aconteceu no arquivo:

- Entra no arquivo e procura as alterações de merge que o git criou automaticamente conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```html
<<<<<<< HEAD:index.html
<div id="footer">contato : email.support@github.com</div>
=======
<div id="footer">
  por favor nos contate em support@github.com
</div>
>>>>>>> iss53:index.html
```

- Depois de localizar o código fazer as alterações, conforme a [documentação de merge do git](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Ramifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-Branching-no-Git-B%C3%A1sico-de-Branch-e-Merge)
- Você deverá fazer o commit das alterações e subir no servidor

  > git commit -m "Merge das alterações"
  >
  > git push

Comment: Essa ultima opção acontece comigo direto, inclusive o Netbeans alerta erro no código por causa disso, a opção 2 resolveu meu problema.

Comment: @AnthraxisBR pois é comigo acontece as vezes também , rs

Comment: @Diogo, depois de analisar aqui acho que é o segundo caso. Como eu vejo qual branch o meu local esta apontando?

Comment: @zwitterion git branch -vv